# How do we wedge the complex differentials $\mathrm{d}z^i$ and $\mathrm{d}\bar z^{\bar j}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra, kahler-manifolds

By the standard definition of the wedge product as an alternated tensor product, I would think we have
$$\tag{1}\mathrm{d}z^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\bar z^{\bar j}=\mathrm{d}z^i\otimes\mathrm{d}\bar z^{\bar j}-\mathrm{d}\bar z^{\bar j}\otimes\mathrm{d}z^i$$
As I understand it, the left side should be a section of exterior algebra $\Lambda^{1,1}M$. However, in the lecture notes I'm reading ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0702063v1.pdf)), this exterior algebra is defined on page 10 as $$\Lambda^{1,1}M:=\Lambda^1T^*M\otimes\Lambda^1\bar T^*M$$
where $T^*M$ is the holomorphic cotangent bundle and $\bar T^*M$ its antiholomorphic counterpart. By inspection, however, the rhs. of (1) can't be a section of this product space because the first term is a section of $\Lambda^1T^*M\otimes\Lambda^1\bar T^*M$, the second factor a section of $\Lambda^1\bar T^*M\otimes\Lambda^1 T^*M$ and the tensor product is not generally commutative.

So how does this actually work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to define the wedge product as an alternating tensor product. The wedge product can just be defined to be a formal symbol satisfying the usual rules. Then everything is fine.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The usual rules being the appropriate (anti-)symmetry conditions?

Comment: The tensor products all make fine sense in the complexified cotangent bundle.

Comment: @TedShifrin They don't to me, so could you please elaborate?

Comment: When $M$ is a complex manifold, $T^*M\otimes\Bbb C \cong T^{(1,0)}M\oplus T^{(0,1)}M$, so $$\otimes^2(T^*M\otimes\Bbb C) \cong (T^{(1,0)}M\otimes T^{(1,0)}M) \oplus (T^{(1,0)}M\otimes T^{(0,1)}M) \oplus (T^{(0,1)}M\otimes T^{(1,0)}M) \oplus (T^{(0,1)}M\otimes T^{(0,1)}M).$$

Comment: @TedShifrin So, roughly, from the first term on the right we get the forms $dz\wedge dz$, from the second two $dz\wedge d\bar z$ and from the last $d\bar z\wedge d\bar z$?

Comment: Yes, of course you mean $dz^i\wedge dz^j$, etc. :) [I couldn't just leave "yes."]

Comment: @TedShifrin This was discussed heavily in the Phys.SE chat and we lapsed into this poor notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref. 1 writes on p.10:

> $$
> \Lambda^k T^{\ast}_{\mathbb{C}} M ~=~ \bigoplus_{j=0}^k \Lambda^{j,k-j} M,\tag{1.11}$$
> *where we defined*
> $$\Lambda^{p,q} M ~:=~ \Lambda^pT^{*(1,0)}M\otimes\Lambda^{q}T^{*(0,1)}M.\tag{1.11b}$$

Here $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional real manifold with a complex structure $J$; the symbol $\otimes$ denotes the standard (un-antisymmetrized) [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) over $\mathbb{C}$; the symbol $\wedge$ denotes the antisymmetrized tensor product/wedge product/[exterior product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) over $\mathbb{C}$; and $T^{\ast}_{\mathbb{C}} M:=\mathbb{C}\otimes T^{\ast} M$ is the complexified cotangent space.

OP got a point that it would be more natural to define

$$\begin{align}\Lambda^{p,q} M ~:=~& \Lambda^pT^{*(1,0)}M\wedge\Lambda^{q}T^{*(0,1)}M\cr ~:=~&\Phi(\Lambda^pT^{*(1,0)}M\otimes\Lambda^{q}T^{*(0,1)}M) ~\subset~ \Lambda^{\bullet} T^{\ast}_{\mathbb{C}} M \end{align}\tag{*}$$

rather than the definition (1.11b). Here the definition (*) is canonically isomorphic to the definition (1.11b). Explicitly, the canonical isomorphism $\Phi$ reads

$$\begin{align}\sum_i\eta_i \otimes \bar{\omega}_i\quad\stackrel{\Phi}\mapsto\quad&\sum_i\eta_i \wedge \bar{\omega}_i, \cr 
\eta_i~\in~\Lambda^pT^{*(1,0)}M,\qquad & \bar{\omega}_i~\in~\Lambda^{q}T^{*(0,1)}M, \end{align}\tag{**}$$

using a hopefully clear notation.

*Example:*

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{d}z^i\otimes\mathrm{d}\bar{z}^{\bar{\jmath}}~\stackrel{\Phi}\mapsto~
\mathrm{d}z^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\bar{z}^{\bar{\jmath}}
~=~&\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{d}z^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\bar{z}^{\bar{\jmath}} 
-\mathrm{d}\bar{z}^{\bar{\jmath}}\wedge\mathrm{d}z^i\right)\cr
~=~&-\mathrm{d}\bar{z}^{\bar{\jmath}}\wedge\mathrm{d}z^i~\in~\Lambda^{\bullet} T^{\ast}_{\mathbb{C}} M .\end{align}\tag{***} $$

Alternatively, if one uses the definition (1.11b), then the equality symbol "$=$" in eq. (1.11) should be interpreted as an isomophism symbol "$\cong$".

References:

1. V. Bouchard, *Lectures on complex geometry, Calabi-Yau manifolds and toric geometry,*  [arXiv:hep-th/0702063](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702063).

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. Perhaps what I'm really looking for is a proof of (1.11).

Comment: The proof of eq. (1.11) [with definition (*) instead of definition (1.11b)] uses basically just the fact that the exterior algebra of forms is a double-graded.

Comment: Ah, but I would like the proof using def (1.11b), if at all possible?

Comment: Could it be that the $=$ in (1.11) should really be a $\cong$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Exactly.

Comment: How is the RHS of $(\ast)$ defined? Constructing the exterior algebra is usually a unary operation $\Lambda(-)$ or $\Lambda^k(-)$ for the individual degrees, isn't it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I updated the answer.